# setResponseBuffering("adaptive") when using jTDS driver?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jtds

The v2.0 MS SQL JDBC driver allows one to set the [adaptive buffering](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879937%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) as such:

```
SQLServerStatement SQLstmt = (SQLServerStatement) stmt;
SQLstmt.setResponseBuffering("adaptive");
```

This is when using:

```
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement;
```

Is the same thing possible when using the jTDS driver?